# Ubuntu 12.04 update and graphics card update

Tags: 12.04, fglrx, software-sources

I have recently updated my Dell M101z system to Ubuntu 12.04. But now there is some problem with the Videos. So I guess I need to update the graphics driver.

I tried following command:

`sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdccclete`

but it is showing warning that

```
E: Unable to locate package fglrx-amdccclete.
```

Kindly help me regarding this

Comment: What problem are you having with the video?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable restricted packages in your software sources.
Go to *Ubuntu Software Center>Edit>Software Sources*
[image: Software Sources]
Now select the third option.
Run `sudo apt-get update` and now try installing fglrx.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting here via google search (perhaps because someone suggested `fglrx` to fix a blank purple screen after login, but `fglrx` couldn't be found), I resolved my issue on Ubuntu 18.04, Macbook Pro 5,1 w/ NVIDIA GeForce 9400M by following https://theitbros.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/. In short:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

(they might already be installed)

```
ubuntu-drivers list
```

just to see what NVIDIA drivers are available, then

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I could see it installed some NVIDIA drivers. I rebooted, and could finally log into a GUI instead of a garbled or blank purple screen.